# Do depth values in AVDepthData (from TrueDepth camera) indicate distance from camera or camera plane?

Tags: scenekit, ios11, iphone-x

Do depth values in AVDepthData (from TrueDepth camera) indicate distance in meters from the camera, or perpendicular distance from the *plane* of the camera (i.e. z-value in camera space)?

My goal is to get an accurate 3D point from the depth data, and this distinction is important for accuracy. I've found lots online regarding OpenGL or Kinect, but not for TrueDepth camera.

FWIW, this is the algorithm I use. I'm find the value of depth buffer at a pixel found using some OpenCV feature detection. Below is the code I use to find real world 3D point at a given pixel at `let cgPt: CGPoint`. This algorithm seems to work quite well, but I'm not sure whether small error is introduced by the assumption of depth being distance to camera plane.

```
let depth = 1/disparity
let vScreen = sceneView.projectPoint(SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -depth))
// cgPt is the 2D coordinates at which I sample the depth
let worldPoint = sceneView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3Make(cgPt.x, cgPt.y, vScreen.z))
```

Comment: how did you end up solving this for the TrueDepth camera data?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of authoritative info either way, but it's worth noticing that capture in a *disparity* (not depth) format uses distances based on a pinhole camera model, as explained in the [WWDC17 session on depth photography](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/). That session is primarily about disparity-based depth capture with back-facing dual cameras, but a lot of the lessons in it are also valid for the TrueDepth camera.

That is, disparity is 1/depth, where depth is distance from subject to imaging plane along the focal axis (perpendicular to imaging plane). Not, say, distance from subject to the focal point, or straight-line distance to the subject's image on the imaging plane.

IIRC the default formats for TrueDepth camera capture are depth, not disparity (that is, depth map "pixel" values are meters, not 1/meters), but lacking a statement from Apple it's probably safe to assume the model is otherwise the same.

Comment: The TrueDepth capture does seem to be in disparity format, and I use 1/disparity to find the depth. I'm a little confused by: _where depth is distance from subject to imaging plane along the focal axis_. Could you elaborate on this a little, in terms of finding a world 3D point?

Comment: Does that mean that the disparity value should be transformed by the inverse projection matrix first?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it measures distance from the camera's plane rather than a straight line from the pinhole. You can test this out by downloading the [Streaming Depth Data from the TrueDepth Camera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera) sample code.

Place the phone vertically 10 feet away from the wall, and you should expect to see one of the following:

1. If it measures from the focal point to the wall as a straight line, you should expect to see a radial pattern (e.g. the point closest to the camera is straight in front of it; the points furthest to the camera are those closer to the floor and ceiling).
2. If it measures distance from the camera's plane, then you should expect the wall color to be nearly uniform (as long as you're holding the phone parallel to the wall).

After downloading the sample code and trying it out, you will notice that it behaves like #2, meaning it's distance from the camera's plane, not from the camera itself.